# Else do nothing SQL query

Tags: sql, if-statement, case

I have a field, `froiexported`, in DB table `claim3` that is either set to one or zero.  I want to run an update where if the criteria in the case statement is met the value in `froiexported` is set to 1 else do nothing. Below will make my results incorrect every day.

```
update claim3
set froiexpoted = 
CASE
     WHEN froimaintdate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
     AND froimaintdate < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
     AND c1.jurst in ('AK', 'AL', 'CA', 'CO', 'FL', 'GA', 'IA', 'IN', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'MA', 'ME', 'MN', 'MO', 'MS', 'NC', 'NE', 'NJ', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VA', 'VT', 'WV')
     THEN '1'
     ELSE '0'
 END
```

Comment: `ELSE froiexpoted`

Comment: If you don't want it to do anything you don't have to use an ELSE clause in your case statement. Just leave it out.

Comment: use a where... this is why filters exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `where` clause instead:

```
update claim3
  set froiexpoted = 1
  where froiexpoted <> 1
    and froimaintdate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,getdate()),0)
    and froimaintdate <  dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),0)
    and c1.jurst in ('AK', 'AL', 'CA', 'CO', 'FL', 'GA', 'IA', 'IN'
      , 'KS','KY', 'LA', 'MA', 'ME', 'MN', 'MO', 'MS', 'NC', 'NE'
      , 'NJ', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VA', 'VT', 'WV'
      )
```

if you need to set 0s for the previous day as well:

```
update claim3
  set froiexpoted = case
    when c1.jurst in ('AK', 'AL', 'CA', 'CO', 'FL', 'GA', 'IA', 'IN'
          , 'KS','KY', 'LA', 'MA', 'ME', 'MN', 'MO', 'MS', 'NC', 'NE'
          , 'NJ', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VA', 'VT', 'WV'
          )
      then 1
    else 0 
    end
  where froimaintdate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,getdate()),0) 
    and froimaintdate <  dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),0)
```

Comment: In theory this would work but being its ran daily would this always set previous days to 0?  Once the 1 is set I want it to stay.

Comment: This code does not set anything to zero @Dizzle -- it only sets things to 1.

Comment: @Dizzle this only updates rows that are for the prior day, and only updates rows that need to be 1 and aren't 1.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting it to 1 if criteria are met, else set to the current value?